# Ordnance Survey grid reference in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, united-kingdom, qgis-custom-function

Is there a way of inserting Ordnance Survey grid reference in a print composer? I know that a grid can be created but I don't wish to insert a grid, I just to need to include the eastings and northings as a text string in the title block.

Comment: do you want any specific grid reference in the title? centre of the map? top left corner?

Comment: You should be able to create a custom function similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226436/getting-extent-of-composer-map-in-pyqgis/226437#226437 to get the center of the map pane

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The example inserts a scale label but I need an OS grid reference label. I have no experience of Python so can anyone adapt the custom function text for me?