# Atlas Map Extent

Tags: qgis, atlas

I am currently trying to grab the map extent of each page in my QGIS atlas.
My python function uses the line:

```
 iface.mapCanvas().extent().toString()
```

which prints the extent just fine. The only problem is the numbers don't match the extent shown in the item properties under 'Extents'. When I draw the polygon from these coordinates the area it covers is huge. The labelled extent does not even update when I switch pages. I have already tried several code snipppets among that the one from: [Getting extent of composer map in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226436/getting-extent-of-composer-map-in-pyqgis) which does not work with my QGIS 2.99 nor does it actually solve my problem.

[image]

Do I need to specify in my function that it should only grab the extent of the @currentfeature or is there something else wrong ?

Comment: @iant The code provided in the link does not work with QGIS 2.99, which is the version I am working with. I tried it in 2.18 and it shows me the scale(not the extent). I adapted the code to provide the extent but again it does not refresh for each atlas page.

Comment: please edit the question to reflect this new information then