# Deleting a common word in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I have a dense attribute table of all the districts in the UK. I want to label the districts but each row in my 'NAME' field has 'District' after it. I wish to take this off, only leaving the name of the district e.g, Wycombe, South Bucks, Chiltern etc...

[image]

Is it possible to create a new field by writing an expression to eliminate all values that match 'district'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to modify the expression used for the label to be:

```
  replace( "NAME" , 'District', '')
```

Or if you are using BoundaryLine then I recommend

```
regexp_replace( "NAME" , 'District.*$', '')
```

to deal with districts like 'Allerdale District (B)'.

Infact for completeness I use:

```
 wordwrap(  replace( 
    regexp_replace( "NAME" , 'District.*$|London Boro$', ''),'(B)',''), 10, ' ')
```

You can avoid the second replace if you can work out how to quote the `(` & `)` in `(B)`.

You may also find the answers to [my question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224556/changing-to-alternate-label-if-first-label-does-not-fit-in-qgis) on switching to numbers instead of names when labeling small polygons useful.

Comment: I haven't used QGIS, but shouldn't that be `'District.*$'`? I'd imagine as it is now the `*` would apply to the the `t`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen you are quite right, I've fixed it