# Labeling rule depending on whether label fits in polygon

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I'm labeling some country polygons with their names. The data have one attribute with the full country name and another one with a short version (e.g. Sweden/SE). I want to label the countries with the long version if it fits completely within the polygon and with the short version otherwise. Is it possible to solve this with rule-based labeling in QGIS?

I know about the draw option "Only draw labels which fit completely within feature". I'm trying to pour this option into a rule if that makes sense.

QGIS version: 3.10.1-A Coruña

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224556/changing-to-alternate-label-if-first-label-does-not-fit-in-qgis help?

Comment: Thanks for this! I was hoping that in the meantime there is a built-in way to solve this, though.