# How to change label names to numbers in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image: townlands]

I'm trying to change label names to just numbers inside each polygon. Also I would like to add a legend with the number = the name of each polygon

Answer (score 5):

For this to be the most consistent you should create a new column (attribute) in the dataset that is the number.

For example to automatically generate numbers in the filed calculator using the expression:

```
@row_number
```

Then you can do categorized symbology with following expression, to add it to the legend:

```
"ID_COLUMN"  || ' - ' || "NAME_COLUMN"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an attribute to your features that you can set to a number, I would use row number for now using the expression:

```
@row_number
```

Then you can use that attribute as a label, and add an Attribute Table to the Print Layout to let people see the number to name relationship.

[image]

If you just want to number some of your polygons and label the others then this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224556/changing-to-alternate-label-if-first-label-does-not-fit-in-qgis) may help